# SSL configuration , Tomcat with Apache and mod_jk

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat6, mod-jk

I am looking to configure SSL with tomcat 6 and apache web server, using the tomcat connector mod_jk. I am pretty new to this, so please bear with me.

I have SSL certificate purchased and configured in tomcat using keystore file. It is perfectly working if access tomcat directly via https. Now i need apache in front of tomcat, my question is, do i need to provide certificate both in tomcat and apache or just the tomcat? Isn't apache supposed to just pass on the request to tomcat (using JkExtractSSL) and let it handle ssl authentication (verification of certificate)?

If certificate paths need to be configured in both apache and tomcat, then i have cert.p7b and certreq.csr files, which are surely not apache compatible, can you please tell how can i do that?

I have the following configuration so far:

httpd.conf:

```
    LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so
    LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so
    JkWorkersFile /usr/local/apache2/conf/workers.properties
    JkShmFile     logs/mod_jk.shm
    JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
    JkLogLevel info
    JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
    JkMount  /mywebapp/* worker1
    JkExtractSSL On
    JkHTTPSIndicator HTTPS
    JkSESSIONIndicator SSL_SESSION_ID
    JkCIPHERIndicator SSL_CIPHER
    JkCERTSIndicator SSL_CLIENT_CERT

    <VirtualHost _default_:80>

       DocumentRoot "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp"

       Alias /mywebap "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp"
       <Directory "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp">
         Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
         AllowOverride NONE
         Order allow,deny
         Allow from all
       </Directory>

      <Location "/mywebapp/WEB-INF/">
         AllowOverride None
         Deny from all
      </Location>

    </VirtualHost>
    Include conf/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
```

httpd-ssl-conf:

```
    <VirtualHost _default_:443>

       DocumentRoot "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp"

        SSLEngine on
        SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXP56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
        SSLOptions +StdEnvVars +ExportCertData

        Alias /mywebapp "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp"
        <Directory "/var/lib/tomcat6/webapps/mywebapp">
           Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
           AllowOverride None
           Order allow,deny
           Allow from all
        </Directory>

        JkMount /mywebapp/* worker1

        <Location "/mywebapp/WEB-INF/">
           AllowOverride None
           Deny from all
        </Location>
     </VirtualHost>
```

Important to mention here is there is no SSLCertificateFile and SSLCertificateKeyFile configured in httpd-ssl.conf, as i am not sure, if it is needed in both tomcat and apache web server. I have it already configured in tomcat using keystore file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSL is used to encrypted communications between a client and your web
service.  If you are putting Apache in front of Tomcat, then you need
to configure Apache with the SSL certificate...and you don't need it
at all for Tomcat, because Apache is handling all of the client
communication.

> If certificate paths need to be configured in both apache and
>   tomcat, then i have cert.p7b and certreq.csr files, which are surely
>   not apache compatible, can you please tell how can i do that?

The `.csr` file is your certificate request and is not important.

[This
question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6211591/export-p7b-file-with-all-the-certificate-chain-into-cer-file)
has links that will help you convert your `.p7b` file into a
PEM-encoded certificate for use with Apache.

You can also export the PEM-encoded certificate from your keystore
using the `-exportcert` command:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias <alias> | openssl x509 -inform der
```

The `JkExtractSSL` directive tells Apache to pass some SSL related
information to Tomcat. According to [this document](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/printer/apache.html), that includes
the following environment variables:

- `SSL_CIPHER`
- `SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE`
- `SSL_SESSION_ID`
- `SSL_CLIENT_CERT_CHAIN_`*n*

Answer (score 0):

well, it seems i cannot comment on your post larsks, so i am posting this as an answer. Thanks for your response. It helped me clear few things. 
So based on your response, I generated `.cer` file from `keytool -exportcert` command as you suggested. However, now when i start apache, i get the following error:

```
  Error: "[error] mod_ssl: Init: Private key not found (OpenSSL library error follows [error] OpenSSL: error:0D084069:asn1 encoding routines:d2i_ASN1_SET:bad tag [error] OpenSSL:
```

I did some google and found that "Apache is unable to read the password protected private key" . Is the key not supposed be exported along with the certificate? apparently not. Then how do i make apache read the private key and where do i find the private key?

Comment: The private key isn't in the certificate. It is still where it was when you created the CSR. If you started with a Java keystore it is still there. You can convert it via a process of exporting the keystore as PKCS12 and then using openssl.exe to convert that. Then you point Apache at that private key file. You'll find the sequence all over the Web, I don't have it to hand.

Comment: Thanks both @EJP and larsks, both of you guys helped me for finding the right solution and cleared my few concepts